# Error "File Not Found"

Tags: xetex, errors, pdf, arabic

I'm writing a series of exercises for my students (In Arabic) and Texmaker keeps telling me "File Not Found". What confuses me is that when I compile the code without the body (Only the preamble) it compiles without any errors. However, when I write something in the body it shows me the error. I am using XeLaTeX by the way.
Here is my code that gets compiled:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.9cm, bottom = 1.2 cm, right=1 cm, left= 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{1pt}
%\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}

\usepackage{romannum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
%======================================================
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}% espace avant
{\topsep}% espace après
{\upshape}% police du corps du théorème
{}% indentation (vide pour rien, \parindent)
{\bfseries\sffamily}% police du titre du théorème
{ :}% ponctuation après le théorème
{\newline}% après le titre du théorème (espace ou \newline)
{%
 % علق الأسطر 25 و 26 و 28
\rule[0.5\baselineskip]{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}%
\newline\fcolorbox{black}{gray!20}{%
\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \textup{#2}}\thmnote{ \textnormal{(#3)}}%
}%
\medskip%
}% spécifications du titre

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{exo}{تمرين}
%======================================================

\title{سلسلة التمارين: المتتاليات العددية}
\author{طارق عسيلة}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\bfseries\sffamily\Large سلسلة التمارين: المتتاليات العددية \\
\large الثالثة ثانوي - شعبة آداب وفلسفة + لغات أجنبية
\end{center}
\textbf{السنة الدراسية: 2020 - 2021} \hfill \textbf{من إعداد: طارق عسيلة}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Here is my code that does not get compiled:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.9cm, bottom = 1.2 cm, right=1 cm, left= 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{1pt}
%\renewcommand{\columnseprule}{1.5pt}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Amiri}

\usepackage{romannum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
%======================================================
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
{\topsep}% espace avant
{\topsep}% espace après
{\upshape}% police du corps du théorème
{}% indentation (vide pour rien, \parindent)
{\bfseries\sffamily}% police du titre du théorème
{ :}% ponctuation après le théorème
{\newline}% après le titre du théorème (espace ou \newline)
{%
 % علق الأسطر 25 و 26 و 28
\rule[0.5\baselineskip]{0.5\textwidth}{1pt}%
\newline\fcolorbox{black}{gray!20}{%
\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ \textup{#2}}\thmnote{ \textnormal{(#3)}}%
}%
\medskip%
}% spécifications du titre

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{exo}{تمرين}
%======================================================

\title{سلسلة التمارين: المتتاليات العددية}
\author{طارق عسيلة}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\bfseries\sffamily\Large سلسلة التمارين: المتتاليات العددية \\
\large الثالثة ثانوي - شعبة آداب وفلسفة + لغات أجنبية
\end{center}
\textbf{السنة الدراسية: 2020 - 2021} \hfill \textbf{من إعداد: طارق عسيلة}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\begin{exo}
\rom{1} - لتكن ($U_n$) متتابية حيث: ($U_n = 3n +5$). أحسب الحدود $U_0, U_1, U_2$. 
\end{exo}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: neither of these fragments can be used to get the behaviour you describe, they will both give errors about missing `\documentclass`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I just forgot that while copying and pasting :D Thank you for telling me, I will add it.

Comment: If I add `\documemtclass{article}` both run without error, show the full error message from the log in the error case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it shows no message in the log. Instead, a window appears saying "File Not Found". It is just very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

So after trying many things I finally could know what was going on with my Code. I just had to delete

```
\usepackage{fourier}
```

From my preamble.